# For some reason finalization of safe handle is killing my application

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

For some reason finalization of safe handle is killing my application if method that should open handle fails.

I have next unmanaged function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
HRESULT
WINAPI
ConnectCommunicationPort(_Out_ PHANDLE hPort)
{
    HRESULT hResult = FilterConnectCommunicationPort(FILEFILTER_PORT_NAME,
        0,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        hPort);

    return hResult;
}
```

[FilterConnectCommunicationPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540460(v=vs.85).aspx)  is declared as

```
_Must_inspect_result_
HRESULT
WINAPI
FilterConnectCommunicationPort (
    _In_ LPCWSTR lpPortName,
    _In_ DWORD dwOptions,
    _In_reads_bytes_opt_(wSizeOfContext) LPCVOID lpContext,
    _In_ WORD wSizeOfContext,
    _In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    _Outptr_ HANDLE *hPort
    );
```

I have custom SafePortHandle class that looks like:

```
public sealed class SafePortHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    public SafePortHandle(IntPtr preexistingHandle, bool ownsHandle)
        : base(ownsHandle)
    {
        SetHandle(preexistingHandle);
    }

    private SafePortHandle()
        : base(true) { }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        if (IsInvalid)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return NativeMethods.CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    DllImport("my.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern Hresult ConnectCommunicationPort(out SafePortHandle handle);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true), ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
}

    internal static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SafePortHandle _portHandle;
        Hresult hr = NativeMethods.ConnectCommunicationPort(out _portHandle);
        if (hr.Failed)
        {
          ..
        }
        ....
    }
```

So if FilterConnectCommunicationPort was executed successfully - all works well, but if FilterConnectCommunicationPort returns error, i see that _portHandle is invalid (-1), and in that case finalization kiils my app with: External component throws an exception seh 0x80004005 (That is Unknown error).  That happens in [SafeHandle.InternalFinalize()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/safehandle.cs) .NET Framework method.

---

Also tried just to use [SafeFileHandle](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/safehandles/safefilehandle.cs)  wich works exact as i need, instead of SafePortHandle- the same result, app crash.

Comment: Just to test: try to return true from ReleaseHandle, if IsInvalid is true. MSDN talks something about returning false `in the event of a catastrophic failure`, invalid handle doesn't seem to be "catastrophic failure".

Comment: @AlexFarber I tried just now to use SafeFileHandle http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/safehandles/safefilehandle.cs wich works exect as i need. (It doesn't returns true, just calls close handle) - the same result, app crash.

Comment: You are presumably filling `handle` with garbage when `FilterConnectCommunicationPort` fails. I guess you need to initialise the `SafePortHandle` only when the hr indicates success. Also, why did you use `SetLastError = true`?

Comment: `CloseHandle` call with invalid handle may crush the program, I don't think that this change is in right direction.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "I guess you need to initialise the SafePortHandle only when the hr indicates success" - it is an option by i saw examples is this way as i did. Marshaler must works correctly with SafeHandle it is designed for this. SafeHandle have properies isInvalid IsClosed, isFullyInitialized. Don't think that is the reason of error.

Comment: @AlexFarber "call with invalid handle may crush the program" if i call _portHandle.Dispose() _portHandle.Close() inside  if (hr.Failed) -- all works with no errors...

Comment: OK, next up remove all this safe handle stuff and use `IntPtr`. Does the problem occur then? Maybe the problem is that the call to `CloseHandle` is happening too late. This would just be a way to suppress it. And prove that it is indeed the call to `CloseHandle` that is behind this. If you are going to wait until the process closes before calling `CloseHandle` then there's little point in calling it at all.

Comment: Anyway, why are you calling `CloseHandle`. Doesn't the base class already do that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. No SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid doesn't.